# C# - efficient random string/int generator

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I'm looking for efficient random generator. I prefer to be string/int generator even though it doesn't really matter that much. I need to copy images and save their names in the database. Because I extract the names from the database there's no need to have some meaningful name, but because I need to copy the images in a directory I have to choose unique names for names of my images. Because every check is a new query to the database I need some efficient random generator so that I'll need minimum number of queries before getting unique name. I know there's a lot algorithms but a quick search didn't help me to find one. I don't want something that will be overkill, after all I'm not encrypting anything I just need the unique names, but still when the number of the images gets bigger I don't want the generating of new unique name to take too much time.

Comment: Why does it have to be random?  If the database has an auto-incrementing primary key, just use the key as the file name.

Comment: Using hash is better idea of any random. As a bonus you will get exception (assuming hash is unique key field) - duplicate found.. yay!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15202298/107625) you might also try:

```
string uniqueName = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

Since the [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) always grow, you have unique values, at least when doing it within one process.

When looking for an integer instead of a string, it is of course:

```
long uniqueValue = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Comment: Watch out though, `Ticks` only changes every few milliseconds!

Answer (score -1):

for a true random generator, use RNGCryptoServiceProvider.
Take a look to that example : [Random Number Generation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/logisimo/random-number-generation-and-windows-forms-encryption-via-C-Sharp-parallel-programming/)

Comment: We normally like to see more then just a link to another website that might or might not be working a year from now.